# how to check if it returns response code is "421"?

Tags: laravel

How to check if response code is 421 because im trying to send email but connection sometimes get disconnect so it return 421 instead of 220

ERROR

```
 Expected response code 220 but got code "421", with message "421 
 Cannot connect to SMTP server 74.125.200.108 (74.125.200.108:587), 
 connect error 10060"
```

Comment: May I know, what exactly you want to do by checking the response code is 421? 
Do you want to handle it manually and return a suitable response?

Comment: can give me the email credential in .env with hiding your mail_password??

Comment: i want like response return a 421 code i want to do something like if =421 {do {this} instead sending email

Comment: Wrap the line in a `try/catch` and check the error code.

Answer (score 0):

You're able to catch errors and handle them accordingly with `try/catch` . For example:

```
try {
    // Code that should be tried
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Handle exception
}
```